# Compiling C++ threads in Windows 8

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to compile this code in Windows 8 using Eclipse Luna.
I get the error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func() {
  std::cout << "Hello thread!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::thread t(func);
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

I used Eclipse MinGW, GCC and Eclipse CygWin, GCC.
I used the settings: -pthread -std=c++11
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags
However the error remains.
I looked into the sources of thread.h. There I found the line

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)
```

I defined `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` and `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1` in
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Preprocessor -> Defined symbols.
This makes the compile error disappear but I get a bunch of other errors which appear to come out from system libraries.
Anyway: defining the symbols looks more like a "hack" than the "official" and recommended solution
By the way: I tried also with Code::Blocks instead of Eclipse but I got the same error.

Comment: remove `std::` from `std::thread`

Comment: @saru95 that wouldn't be wise as it breaks compatibility with existing code. But using `using std::thread` allows you to just use `thread` and be platform independent anyway.

Comment: I tried this but it did not change anything

Comment: "I defined `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS`" -- this is a build-time configuration option for the C++ standard library. Changing this on the client side won't change what is compiled in your standard library. Use the installers at http://mingw-w64.org to get a functional toolchain.